# automatically opening URL with google assistant/google home

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I have been searching a lot i couldn't find an answer... so any help would be really appreciated, I want google assistant to open certain URL automatically.

Been giving new commands on console.dialogflow.com.

Examples available out there are displaying cards or about playing media files
I have managed to put "Link out suggestion" and it shows it on google assistant and it is clickable, but i want it to open that certain URL automatically.
Is it possible
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In short, no you cannot automatically open URLs. The link out suggestion is intended to give the functionality of shifting to a browser while not creating a jarring user experience.

Comment: So it is not possible to say for example ' hey google open www.......com' ? even coding it isnt possible ?

Comment: It's not something that a 3rd party action is able to do

Comment: Your action can make an API request to fetch website content and present it to the user in a conversational way (segmented into short blocks of characters)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite possible.
Goto routines> add new> in the last you will see an option try to create your own and write "open https://yourdomain.com".
Or please simply visit this as I am not good for explaining
https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/232545?hl=en